# Moment generating function for sum of independent random variables same as joint mgf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

I'm seeing in general that for moment generating functions, the mgf of $X+Y$ where $X,Y$ are independent random variables is $M_{X+Y}(t) = M_X(t)M_Y(t)$. I'm also seeing that the joint mgf is given by $M_{(X,Y)}(t) = M_X(t_1)M_Y(t_2)$.

I'm not understanding why these two things would have the same formula. That is, why does $M_{(X,Y)}(t) = M_{X+Y}(t)$ for independent random variables? Would appreciate both a mathematical and heuristic explanation of why these are the same. I believe I may be making an error, however, in thinking the two formulas are the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They don't have the same formula.  $M_X(t) M_Y(t)$ is a function of a single variable $t$, whereas $M_X(t_1) M_Y(t_2)$ is a function of two variables, $t_1$ and $t_2$.  You might say, but what if $t_1 = t_2$?  Then yes, you get the MGF of $X + Y$.  But they are no more the same as if you were to claim that $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ is equivalent to $g(x) = 2x^2$.  They are drastically different functions.

Answer (score 2):

The first formula is because $\mathsf M_{Z}(t)=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{tZ})$ by definition, and when the variables are independent :-
$$\begin{align}\mathsf M_{X+Y}(t)&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{t(X+Y)})\\&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{tX}\mathrm e^{tY})\\&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{tX})\,\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{tY})&&\text{via independence}\\&=\mathsf M_X(t)\,\mathsf M_Y(t)\end{align}$$

---

The second formula should be $\mathsf M_{X,Y}(t_1,t_2)=\mathsf M_X(t_1)\mathsf M_Y(t_2)$ .  (Perhaps $t$ is the vector $\langle t_1,t_2\rangle$ in your sourcebook?). $$\begin{align}\mathsf M_{X,Y}(t_1,t_2)&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{\langle t_1,t_2\rangle\cdot\langle X,Y\rangle})\\&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{t_1X+t_2Y})\\&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{t_1X}\mathrm e^{t_2Y})\\&=\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{t_1X})\mathsf E(\mathrm e^{t_2Y})\\&=\mathsf M_X(t_1)\,\mathsf M_Y(t_2)\end{align}$$